# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect') on react-unity-webgl

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, next.js

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tceyd.png)

I try to add Webgl in my next.js project by using react-unity-webgl. At first, it displays correctly but when I change a page to another page this error have been occur. I have no idea why it happens and I'm new in nextjs and react-unity-webgl, Can anyone help me with this problem?

this is my code

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { Unity, useUnityContext }from "react-unity-webgl";

const FloorPlan = (props) => {

const { unityProvider } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.data",
    frameworkUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.wasm",
  });

  return (
  ...
    <div style={{width:"100%",marginTop:"20px"}}>
    <Unity unityProvider={unityProvider} style={{ width:550, height: 300,marginLeft:"15px"}}/>
    </div>
  ...
  )
  
  export default FloorPlan
```

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs Project first processing and render in server and then send to client .
To prevent processing "react-unity-webgl" in server-side :

UnityComponent.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Unity, useUnityContext }from "react-unity-webgl";

function UnityComponent() {

  const { unityProvider } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.data",
    frameworkUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "/Unity/floor1/Build/Floor 1.wasm",
  });

  return (
    <>
        <Unity unityProvider={unityProvider} style={{ width:550, height: 300,marginLeft:"15px"}}/>
    </>
  ) 
}

export default UnityComponent;
```

and

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React from "react"

const UnityComponent = dynamic(() => import('./UnityComponent'), {
  ssr: false,
})
const FloorPlan = (props) => {


  return (
    <div style={{width:"100%",marginTop:"20px"}}>
      <UnityComponent />
    </div>
  )
}
  export default FloorPlan;
```

Comment: I try this but the error is still or maybe I should update my nextjs

Comment: Did you use getBoundingClientRect anywhere in your code? @Phineas

Comment: In Floor 1.framework.js maybe my 3d model has a problem. Thx for your answer.

Comment: @Phineas I'm struggling with the same issue right now. Any luck on a resolution? https://github.com/jeffreylanters/react-unity-webgl/discussions/412 I made this git post here on the react-unity-webgl discussion to see if I can find something.